# NSTableView Background image

Tags: cocoa, background-image, nstableview, appkit

I want to set the background of an NSTableView but I don't know how to do it. I have tried this but it did not work:

```
[[tableview cell]setBackgroundImage:[NSImage imageNamed:"xyz.jpg"]];
```

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: First you should not use cells. They're deprecated. Use view based tables. Second please clarify if you mean row, cell or table background

Comment: If you mean the actual NSTableView, setting the background of a single cell  wouldn't change the background of the entire view, just that particular cell.

Answer (score 1):

Subclass NSTableView and override:

```
-(void)drawBackgroundInClipRect:(NSRect)clipRect
```

Answer (score -1):

You can solve this issue with a different approach. Put table view as subview of an image view. Apply your image with image view . Change the background color of table view and it's scroll view to clear color.